# How to compare a List, with elements of other list JAVA

Tags: java

I have two diferents lists. Where inside de first list has a Array.
I need make a new list, comparing the values of the second list with the Array of 
first list. Keeping the other elements of first list.

Example:

```
List1:
      {
       name:"";
       fone:"";
       numbers:["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]
       }
numbers2:
      {
       1;
       4;
       6;
       }
ListResult =           {
       name:"";
       fone:"";
       numbers:["1", "4", "6"]
       }
```

Comment: You don't have two lists. You have something that looks vaguely like JSON objects. How is this information stored in Java? That is, what classes are you using?

Comment: You also haven't defined "compare".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try this.

```
ListResult = list1.getNumbers().stream().filter(n-> number2.contains(Integer.parseInt(n))).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I assumed that your "arrays" like numbers1 and numbers 2 are actually java lists.

Answer (score 0):

As Silvio mentioned, the data given looks like JSON objects. 
Assuming If you are two lists (as in collection), you could use retainAll or removeAll provided by Java for a Collection. 
Please refer : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeAll(java.util.Collection)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your input format is too confusing, this is the best I can do as far as I could understand it.

If you want a custom list, (something like as JSON object) you should have a class like this

```
public class CustomList {
private String name;
private String fone; 
private ArrayList<String> numbers;
private ArrayList<Integer> numbers2;

public String toString(){
    String output = "";
    output = "{" +
            "\nname: " + this.name +
            "\nfone: " + this.fone + 
            "\nnumbers: " + numbers.toString() +
            "\n}";
    return output;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getFone() {
    return fone;
}
public void setFone(String fone) {
    this.fone = fone;
}
public ArrayList<String> getNumbers() {
    return numbers;
}
public void setNumbers(ArrayList<String> numbers) {
    this.numbers = numbers;
}
public ArrayList<Integer> getNumbers2() {
    return numbers2;
}
public void setNumbers2(ArrayList<Integer> numbers2) {
    this.numbers2 = numbers2;
}
}
```

---

```
public class ListAnalyzer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CustomList myList = new CustomList();
        myList.setName("\"\"");
        myList.setFone("\"\"");
        myList.setNumbers(new ArrayList<String>());
        myList.getNumbers().add("1");
        myList.getNumbers().add("4");
        myList.getNumbers().add("6");
        System.out.println(myList.toString());
    }

}
```

---

**OUTPUT**

```
{
name: ""
fone: ""
numbers: [1, 4, 6]
}
```